# Automapper flatten object with inheritance

Tags: c#, automapper

I have model with properties that I need to map to entities that inhers from abstract class ClassAModel and ClassBModel is one to one with ClassA and ClassB

```
public class Model
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public ClassAModel ClassAModel { get; set; }
    public ClassBModel ClassBModel { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : AbstractClass
{

}

public class ClassB : AbstractClass {

}
```

I don't know how to tell automapper to map ClassA from ClassAModel property

Comment: So do you want to map `Model` to `ClassA` using the properties from `ClassAModel` and the number from the `Model`. Maybe look at  `ConstructProjectionUsing`

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Answer (score -1):

This answer presumes that you are trying to map `Model` to `ClassA` using the properties from `ClassAModel` and the number property from `Model`:

```
CreateMap<Model, ClassA>()
    .ConstructProjectionUsing(x => new ClassA(){Name = x.ModelClassA.Name, Number = x.Number});
```

This answer presumes to you want to map `Model` to both an instance of `ClassA` and `ClassB`. This uses dynamic to wrap the two objects.

```
CreateMap<Model, dynamic>()
                .ConstructProjectionUsing(x =>  new { A = new ClassA() { Name = x.ModelClassA.Name, Number = x.Number },
                    B = new ClassB() { Department  = x.ModelClassA.Name, Number = x.Number }});
```

Hopefully these are helpful.

To reduce the manual mapping you can do something like this instead (untested code):

```
CreateMap<Model, ClassA>()
    .ConstructProjectionUsing(x => Mapper.Map<ClassA>(x.ModelClassA))
    .ForMember(x => x.Number, y => y.MapFrom(src => src.Number));

CreateMap<Model, ClassB>()
    .ConstructProjectionUsing(x => Mapper.Map<ClassB>(x.ClassBModel))
    .ForMember(x => x.Number, y => y.MapFrom(src => src.Number));

CreateMap<Model, dynamic>().ConstructProjectionUsing(x => new {A = Mapper.Map<Model, ClassA>(x), B = Mapper.Map<Model, ClassB>(x)});
```

Comment: There is nothing auto about this mapping.